# How do I make the .mtl file contain a color for every coordinate

Tags: export

My .mtl file looks like

## Blender MTL File: 'None'

## Material Count: 1

newmtl Torso1Mtl
Ns 1000.000000
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.800000 0.000000 0.000000
Ks 0.200000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd Torso1Tex.png
map_Ka Torso1Tex.png
map_d Torso1Tex.png

so when I try to import an .obj file with .mtl file into Roblox Studio and this is the reason the object isn't colored.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to finish my sentence. So I want to know, what can I do to make it contain a color for every coordinate, just like the title says.

Comment: Seems like you'll find your answer here:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21303/how-can-i-include-vertex-color-information-in-obj-files

Comment: Thanks but, it has to be .obj and .mtl to be able to convert it into Roblox, and the 2nd option, I think he said make the .obj file itself have the color data, which is bad, since I need them to be seperate, also I don't have much experience other than Lua :/